# Laravel how to access the relation data on a custom pivot class

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova, laravel-auditing

I wan't to store updates in pivot tables inside a separate table called `audits_pivot`.

To do that I need to sort of hook into the `attached` event on the model (State), which as I found out [doesn't](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/28050) [really](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-58-and-syncing-event?page=1#reply=501690) exist. What I can do is to listen on the custom pivot class (LicenceState) for `static::saving` to be called, since that is the equivalent to 'attached'. Unfortunately does the callback of `static::saving` not contain any information about what the pivot was attached to.

There are libraries like [this one](https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-pivot/) from fico7489, but that doesn't work together with [Laravel Nova](https://nova.laravel.com/), which I'm using.

How can I access things like the name and Id of the Model that the pivot row was attached to?

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as EloquentModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot as EloquentPivot;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable as AuditableTrait;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;

abstract class Pivot extends EloquentPivot implements Auditable
{
    use AuditableTrait;

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function ($model)  {
            // How can I access here things like the name and Id of the Model that the pivot row was attached to?
            // What I'm looking for is basically this: 
            // savePivotAudit('attached', 12, 'App\Licence', 'App\State', 51, '2020-01-14 13:55:58');
        });
    }

    private function savePivotAudit($eventName, $id, $relation, $pivotId, $date)
    {
        return app('db')->table('audits_pivot')->insert([
            'event' => $eventName,
            'auditable_id' => $id,
            'auditable_type' => $this->getMorphClass(),
            'relation_id' => $pivotId,
            'relation_type' => $relation,
            'parent_updated_at' => $date,
        ]);
    }
}

class License extends EloquentModel {}

class State extends EloquentModel
{
    use AuditableTrait;


    public function licenses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(License::class)
            ->using(LicenseState::class);
    }
}

class LicenseState extends Pivot {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Accountant](https://altek.gitlab.io/accountant/) package does what you want.

It supports many to many relations (i.e. pivot tables), by using [Eventually](https://altek.gitlab.io/eventually/), which adds events for `attach()`, `detach()`, `updateExistingPivot()`, `sync()` and `toggle()`.

There's not even a need for using [custom intermediate models](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models).

The documentation covers all aspects of installation, configuration and usage.

Comment: I tried using it already, but I couldn't get it to work. Pivot events aren't recorded when I use the `Eventually` and `Recordable` traits on the `State` model, but instead it adds multiple rows to the ledgers table where the event is 'retrieved' and the 'modified' column is empty.

In addition to that, when the `Licence` model also has the `Recordable` trait, one attach creates up to 40 ledger entries at once.

Should I open a ticket on GitLab?

Comment: You probably missed something when configuring. Sure, open a ticket if you think it's a bug.